# Non-Static String Variables from MainActivity to Fragment Issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` that contains a bundle of strings, these strings can be modified in this activity by the user. The `activity_main` consists of the `mainActivity` and a `fragment`. I would like these strings to come to the `FragmentActivity()`.
The issue is that I cannot use bundles, as it returns null, but I understand that this is because, for the mainActivity the value of the strings is `null` at `onStart` and hence when you send it over as a bundle to the fragment at the start, it sends all the strings with a `null` value (As the user hasn't edited the strings yet in the `MainActivity`). 
How can I get the strings directly from the `MainActivity` Class even after they have been modified.

My current solution:

MainActivity();

```
Bundle bundle1 =new Bundle();
bundle1 .putString("string1", string1);
bundle1 .putString("string2", string2);
Fragment Fragment = new Fragment();
Fragment.setArguments(bundle1);
```

FragmentClass();

```
final Bundle bundle1 = this.getArguments();

if(bundle1 != null){
    string1 = getArguments().getString("string1");
    string2 = getArguments().getString("string2");
}
```

Comment: When you call getString you appear to be handing in your string variable rather than the original `"String1"` that you passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the strings directly from the MainActivity Class even
>   after they have been modified.

**Use SharedPreferences---**

```
public void setSetting(String key, String value) {

    if(getActivity() != null)
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ProjectPref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);

        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public String getSetting(String key, String def) {

    try
    {
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ProjectPref", 0);
    return settings.getString(key, def);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

**MainActivity();**

```
setSetting("String1",String1);
setSetting("String2",String2);
```

*NOTE:* Use the method `setSetting` at the time user modified the strings in order to get the latest values stored in the Shared Preferences.

**FragmentClass();**

```
String string1 = getSetting("String1", "");
String string2 = getSetting("String2", "");
```

Here you can get those values in the variables string1 and string2 respectively.

More on this on [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 1):

You go wrong over here

```
if(bundle1 != null){
string1 = getArguments().getString(string1);
string2 = getArguments().getString(string2);
}
```

**Correct** with below:

```
 if(bundle1!= null){
   String string1=getArguments().getString("String1"); // Provide Double Quotes 
   String string2=getArguments().getString("String2"); // Provide Double Quotes 
  }
```

Comment: Hi my apologies, i had just changed that for testing. This still doesnt work because its taking the first value of the string when the App starts (the string value at the start is null) . It needs to take the value of the string when after its been modified by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your not acquiring a string from the bundle.

```
String1 = getArguments().getString(String1);
```

Needs to be

```
String1 = getArguments().getString("String1");
```

Comment: Hi my apologies, i had just changed that for testing. This still doesnt work because its taking the first value of the string when the App starts (the string value at the start is null) . It needs to take the value of the string when after its been modified by the user.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is that your not creating a fragment of type FragmentClass, your just creating a plain old Fragment and allocating it your arguments instead of your fragment class. Try FragmentClass Fragment = new FragmentClass();